# I wand to identify the font in this image?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

Please identify the font in this image.

Comment: Hi Hari Krishnan! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366/8708) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Put on hold "so that your question can be answered" ... I think we've got this one guys.

Comment: @plainclothes Point taken, but we really don't want questions like this to be exemplary of what to ask on this site. So closed it stays. :)

Comment: @Vincent fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh how I hate that face ...

**[Mistral](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/mistral/), King of the Ugly Scripts**.

[image]